# How to call GetStockObject in the Rust Crate for Windows

Tags: winapi, rust

How does one translate the following Win32 call:

HBRUSH hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);

rather than calling CreateSolidColorBrush

Answer (score 0):

The bindings for `GetStockObject` are documented [here](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/fn.GetStockObject.html). It accepts one of the [`GET_STOCK_OBJECT_FLAGS`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/struct.GET_STOCK_OBJECT_FLAGS.html) values (such as [`WHITE_BRUSH`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/constant.WHITE_BRUSH.html)) and returns an [`HGDIOBJ`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/struct.HGDIOBJ.html). If you are calling an API that accepts an `HGDIOBJ` (like `SelectObject`) there's nothing more you need to do:

```rust
let hbrBackground = unsafe { GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) };
```

If you do need the specific GDI object type, i.e. [`HBRUSH`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/struct.HBRUSH.html) you're going to have to create one:

```rust
let hbrBackground = unsafe { GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) };
let hbrBackground = HBRUSH(hbrBackground.0);
```

or

```rust
let hbrBackground = HBRUSH(unsafe { GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) }.0);
```

for short.